# Tabbed Activity background fixed (not movable)

Tags: android, android-fragments, background, tabactivity

I have a Tabbed Activit. I created 3 fragments with relative xml. I want to set a fixed background for all fragments. Now I set a background in each xml and obviously tha background change when i swipe from a fragment to other fragment.

How can I do?

Thanks
Sorry for my english

Comment: Why don't you set the background in the style.xml, This will make your background common for all.

Comment: you are right. now I have already solved by the method of Abbath. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to set a background for the activity, and set transparent background for the fragments:

`android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

Also [this stack flow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382426/fragment-has-default-white-background-on-replace-instead-of-transparent-one) might help you.